# Doing Halton sampling and sequence using Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to do quasi-random Halton sampling and sequence using python. Is there any library I can use regarding this issue and plotting the output?
I would be so grateful if you could assist me.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to do it using first principles, you can use the code that is presented on the [Wikipedia page for Halton sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halton_sequence):

```py
def halton(b):
    """Generator function for Halton sequence."""
    n, d = 0, 1
    while True:
        x = d - n
        if x == 1:
            n = 1
            d *= b
        else:
            y = d // b
            while x <= y:
                y //= b
            n = (b + 1) * y - x
        yield n / d
```

Here is a way to take the first 256 points of the 2- and 3- sequences, and plot them:

```py
n = 256
df = pd.DataFrame([
    (x, y) for _, x, y in zip(range(n), halton(2), halton(3))
], columns=list('xy'))

ax = df.plot.scatter(x='x', y='y')
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

[image]

**Addendum** "if I want to take for example 200 points and 8 dimensions for all sequences what should I do?"

Assuming you have access to a prime number sequence generator, then you can use e.g.:

```py
m = 8
p = list(primes(m * m))[:m]  # first m primes

n = 200
z = pd.DataFrame([a for _, *a in zip(range(n), *[halton(k) for k in p])])

>>> z
            0         1       2         3         4         5         6         7
0    0.500000  0.333333  0.2000  0.142857  0.090909  0.076923  0.058824  0.052632
1    0.250000  0.666667  0.4000  0.285714  0.181818  0.153846  0.117647  0.105263
2    0.750000  0.111111  0.6000  0.428571  0.272727  0.230769  0.176471  0.157895
3    0.125000  0.444444  0.8000  0.571429  0.363636  0.307692  0.235294  0.210526
4    0.625000  0.777778  0.0400  0.714286  0.454545  0.384615  0.294118  0.263158
..        ...       ...     ...       ...       ...       ...       ...       ...
195  0.136719  0.576132  0.3776  0.011662  0.868520  0.089213  0.567474  0.343490
196  0.636719  0.909465  0.5776  0.154519  0.959429  0.166136  0.626298  0.396122
197  0.386719  0.057613  0.7776  0.297376  0.058603  0.243059  0.685121  0.448753
198  0.886719  0.390947  0.9776  0.440233  0.149512  0.319982  0.743945  0.501385
199  0.074219  0.724280  0.0256  0.583090  0.240421  0.396905  0.802768  0.554017
```

**Bonus**

Primes sequence using [Atkin's sieve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number):

```py
import numpy as np

def primes(limit):
    # Generates prime numbers between 2 and n
    # Atkin's sieve -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number
    sqrtLimit = int(np.sqrt(limit)) + 1

    # initialize the sieve
    is_prime = [False, False, True, True, False] + [False for _ in range(5, limit + 1)]

    # put in candidate primes:
    # integers which have an odd number of
    # representations by certain quadratic forms
    for x in range(1, sqrtLimit):
        x2 = x * x
        for y in range(1, sqrtLimit):
            y2 = y*y
            n = 4 * x2 + y2
            if n <= limit and (n % 12 == 1 or n % 12 == 5): is_prime[n] ^= True
            n = 3 * x2 + y2
            if n <= limit and (n % 12 == 7): is_prime[n] ^= True
            n = 3*x2-y2
            if n <= limit and x > y and n % 12 == 11: is_prime[n] ^= True

    # eliminate composites by sieving
    for n in range(5, sqrtLimit):
        if is_prime[n]:
            sqN = n**2
            # n is prime, omit multiples of its square; this is sufficient because
            # composites which managed to get on the list cannot be square-free
            for i in range(1, int(limit/sqN) + 1):
                k = i * sqN # k ∈ {n², 2n², 3n², ..., limit}
                is_prime[k] = False
    for i, truth in enumerate(is_prime):
        if truth: yield i
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. if I want to take for example 200 points and 8 dimentions for all sequences what should I do?

Comment: I do really appreciate you. sorry for the questioning. if I want to demonstrate the output with a scatter plot how would be the code? (for example with matplotlib.)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, SciPy is the main scientific computing package, and it [contains a Halton sequence generator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.qmc.Halton.html), among other QMC functions.

For plotting, the standard way with SciPy is matplotlib; if you're not familiar with that, the [tutorial for SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/general.html) is also a great place to start.

A basic example:

```py
from scipy.stats import qmc
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sampler = qmc.Halton(d=2, scramble=True)
sample = sampler.random(n=5)

plt.plot(sample)
```

Comment: Thank you for help. But when I want to import this error raise: ImportError: cannot import name 'qmc' from 'scipy.stats' (C:\winapps\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py)

Comment: The QMC module of SciPy was added in the second most recent version (1.7.0) and requires Python 3.7+. Perhaps your SciPy module hasn't been updated to that version?